# Booting from Live USB leads to command line instead of menu

Tags: 12.04, installation, live-usb, uefi

I'm trying to install 12.04 x64 from a USB stick. I created the Live USB as per instructions from ubuntu.com, however, after choosing to boot from USB I get stuck with a command line, titled GRUB. When I type "install", it replies that "no kernel is loaded".

On my other PC everything is fine, the Live USB boots just fine. The one I'm trying to install to has UEFI mobo - maybe that's the problem? However, fiddling with UEFI settings in mobo setup (UEFI/Legacy) has no visible effect.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, the problem was that I had a copy of Windows installed in legacy mode. After forcing legacy in bios and forcing the USB to appear a hard disk, the live USB booted into menu. Writing this as Ubuntu installs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

In the command line, type exactly this:

```
 /casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --nomodeset
```

This command will execute, and then you will be able to get to the graphical install.

Enjoy your installation!

Comment: It replies "unknown command". I'm pretty sure I haven't mistyped anything (the possibility still remains, of course).

Comment: What happens if you just type `/casper/vmlinuz`. It should display text and then nothing happens. Restart your computer. This is to see if the first part of the command works

Comment: it reads the same thing - - "unknown command"

Comment: ok, try to type just `file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --nomodeset`

Comment: nothing happens - after I press enter, the cursor just moves to the next (empty) line